# How to turn off Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'. ts (2322) and (2345)

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to turn off

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)
```

The code I write uses a null type check because it can't be empty string check. If I do what typescript wants and set string as undefined or as empty it creates a whole lot of other errors everywhere like

```
Variable 'value2' is used before being assigned.ts(2454
```

Is there a flag to turn this off?

example code:

```
function check(value: string, value2: string = null) { // error here

    if (value2==null) {
       // 
    }

}
```

Example 2:

```
var value: string = null; // error here
```

Also, I want to turn off this one:

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Is there a typescript compile option for this?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try set `strictNullChecks: false` in compilerOptions section of your tsconfig.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

Answer (score 6):

According to your code, the actual type is `string | null`.

Example 1:

```
function check(value: string, value2: string | null = null) {

    if (value2==null) {
       // 
    }

}
```

Example 2:

```
var value: string | null = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Above the statement that causes the error, you can write a `// @ts-ignore` comment to tell Typescript to ignore it.

Although, instead of `value2: string = null` (null is not a string type), you may want to have something like: `value2?: string` to signify that it is optional (seems like that's how it is intended to be).

```
function check(value: string, value2?: string) {

    if (value2 === undefined) {
       // 
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you could write `value2: string | null = null`